# Can't load KML Layer on Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, kmz

I created my Google Map loaded successfully an Google Map KML from Google Examples. But when I want to load my own kml file which I can open on Google Earth it doesn't load. I uploaded my kml file (11 MB) to my ftp, it is accessible. Is there any limits or should I convert it?

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://blablabla.com/MyOwn.kml',
        //url: 'http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems the KML-documentation has been modified.

Previously there has been a list of limits, including  a filesize-limit of 3MB for a single KML-File , but I can't find this list anymore.

I've tested it and it's clear that now there is a limit of 2MB for a single KML-file.

See also: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9157

Comment: Thank you. The reason is 2MB limit. Maybe have to try load multiple KML files.

Comment: I'm afraid this will not help much, there is also a limit for the sum of the filesize of all loaded KML-documents